# How can I see the location of an external Delta table in Spark using Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

If I create an external table in Databricks, how can I check its location (in Delta lake) using an SQL query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done by using the following command.

```
describe detail <the table>
```

The location would be listed in the column `location`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by using of multiple ways .

```
%sql 
show create table database.tablename
```

or

```
%sql 

desc formatted database.tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following sql query to check the table location:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE EXTENDED <your-table-name>
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-describe-table) for more details on using `DESCRIBE`.